# ROS Indigo/Jade on ARM 64 bit?

Tags: ros, 64bit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Tomorrow Nvidia Jetson TX1 will be available in USA, it will be a big step for robotics...

Have anyone tried to compile ROS on 64 bit ARM systems?
I do not know if all the dependencies can be satisfied... I'm really curious to start testing it.

Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220979/ros-indigo/jade-on-arm-64-bit?/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2015-11-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2015-11-15**:
I'm running ROS Indigo on TK1

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2015-11-16**:
Jetson TK1 has a 32 bit ARM and I use it without problems since about one year and half. My doubt is about the Jetson TX1, based on the Tegra X1 that is a 64bit SoC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most ROS packages should work on ARM64. We already support 32 and 64bit x86 and most things work on armhf. So filling in the matrix is a minimal step forward.

You're right that the system dependencies are usually the limiting factor. I would expect at least up through desktop to work. With more arm64 boards coming out soon we expect to have more experience and demand for those system dependencies so hopefully they will all get filled in.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I almost have it compiled. Hung up on wxPython. Had to build rosinstall-generator rosdep and a few others. Running it in a chroot on a tx1. Gotta do the chroot to a real 64 bit fs since the tx1 has a 32 bit fs now. Managed to get it to compile and roscore started up but then an error trying to use it. So something still not kosher. WxPython is the hang up. Can't find any pre-compiled binaries for arm64 yet. Managed to get it to compile but there is something wrong with it I think. Next up going to move wxpython over to the intel box and try a cross compile on it. I know that set-up is right I'm running on the kernel I made on it.

---

Originally posted by [griz11](https://answers.ros.org/users/25304/griz11/) with karma: 11 on 2015-12-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2015-12-11**:
When I submitted this question I did not know that the Jetson TX1 has a 32bit FS.
After that I received it, I knew about this fact and installed ROS following the same procedure used for the Jetson TK1. Now I'm using it without any problem.
Which advantages can I get using a 64bit FS and so a 64bit

**Comment by [griz11](https://answers.ros.org/users/25304/griz11/) on 2015-12-12**:
Twice the bandwidth for transferring data. Especially if the software is optimized to pack 2 32 bit values into 1 64 bit value before transferring. Hopefully it won't be long before the tx1 is 64 bit. Finding the problems now is optimum. Fire up a 64bit fs on the jetson and you will see it.